# Почему люди бывают затурканные?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Есть такое выражение "затурканный" - то есть, тот, у кого голова идет кругом от обилия поручений, дел и обязанностей. Задерганный - наверное, самый близкий синоним.
Но интересно было бы узнать, почему говорят "затурканный"? При чем тут Турция или турки?
Спасибо

Comment: Конечно, без турок тут не обошлось)

Comment: @Инна. Турки тут абсолютно ни при чём .

Comment: Следопыт, если Вы заметили, в моей фразе явная ирония.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем "**ПОЛНЫЙ ЦЕРКОВНО-СЛАВЯНСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ**" под редакцией магистра **Гр. Дьяченко** на стр. 740 [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0740.htm) и видим: << **Турить (и тулить) = погонять, понуждать.** >> Этимологию автор выводит как обще-индоевропейскую, приводя словоформу из санскрита << *тур* (*турjjате*). ====================================================================================== [image] ========================================================================================= То есть, <<**ЗАТУРКАННЫЙ**>> означает типа, как *ПОГОНЯЕМЫЙ*, *ПОНУЖДАЕМЫЙ*. Схоже, как *ЗАМОТАННЫЙ* (*в смысле мотаться* [по принуждению] *туда-сюда*), *ЗАМУЧЕННЫЙ* (*работой, приказаниями и т.п.*),  *ЭКСПЛУАТИРУЕМЫЙ*. ===================================================================================== P.S. Ещё я помню, когда некоторое время работал в цирке, в тех. персонале, то имел дело с верблюдами. Команда *ВСТАТЬ* из положения полу-лёжа (привычного для отдыхающего верблюда ) верблюдам подавалась традиционно, по-восточному, звучала, как <<**ТУР**>>. Тот же схожий смысл *принуждения*.

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но тогда будет затуренный, а не затурканный.
туров турили, погоняли и пасли, потом это стало коровой.
Вытуркивать как то не катит.

Comment: @petro. Тур или турпан это дикая лошадь, когда-то очень давно, во времена домонгольской Киевской Руси, водившаяся в Восточной Европе. Вымершее или истребленное охотниками животное. Это НЕ КОРОВА. Корова - парнокопытное, как верблюд, а тур (и другие лошадиные - лошадь, осёл) -  непарнокопытное.  Никто туров, равно, как и других диких животных, никогда не пас и не погонял, - такое, в принципе, невозможно - это скажет любой мало-мальски грамотный натуалист.

Comment: вообще то современный тур это козел, 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Западнокавказский_тур

а тарпан -лошадка.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тарпан

ну да ладно, 

еще один тур

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Тур_(бык)

Answer (score 0):

Если из многочисленных синонимов выбрать ветку **загнанный, затюканный, затравленный, задавленный, заезженный**, просматривается версия "за**тур**канный - за**тор**канный", где **тор** (дорога, путь, калея) указывает на смысл, понятный всякому путнику или взявшему на себя большую, монотонную работу.

Answer (score -1):

[Вот здесь](http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=88096) дискуссия на эту тему. Мне понравилось:

> Укр. затуркувати, сов. затуркати
> "заморачивать, доводя до отупения".
> Вероятно, от туркати "ворковать (о
> голубях), тарахтеть, талдычить,
> повторять одно и то же"
> звукоподражательного происхождения.

Если вспомнить, что у Даля "туркать"="перешёптываться", похоже на истину.

Comment: @greydog. Ну, а что, если ваше << укр. за-ТУРКУВ-ати >> отождествить с именем Томаса Торквемады (ТОРКВ-емада)?! Томас Торквемада (1420-1496 г.г.) -  Великий инквизитор Испании. Тоже ж, ведь, какой ещё человекомучитель был, - Берия отдыхает!

Comment: Не думаю, что украинские хуторяне знали, кто такой Торквемада.

Comment: 

@greydog. Ну, разумеется, они не имели ни малейшего понятия о Торквемаде. Я же просто шучу...  Перечитайте ещё раз мой ответ, может, он понравится Вам больше.

Comment: Я его прочёл. Не бьётся с Далем (он считал, что "туркать" - из курского говора, со значением "перешёптываться", "шушукаться" и т.п.).
Либо Даль не знал церковно-славянского, либо между "турить" и "туркать" - пропасть.

Comment: @greydog. Я считаю, здесь имеет место первый вариант - "либо Даль не знал церковно-славянского". С "прощелыгой"  Вл. Даль тоже дал маху именно по этой причине.